# HTML, CSS: Form input list with scrollbar, but not a dropdown, all options visible

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code for a dropdown list input in a form:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <label for="browser">Choose your browser from the list:</label>
  <input list="browsers" name="browser" id="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Edge">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
    ...
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

It shows this:

[image]

However it only shows the list after I click on the `input` element.

I'd like the dropdown list to always be shown. Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: According to the [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-datalist-element), `datalist` element and its children should be hidden in the rendering. Also, exposing such a long list at all times can be overwhelming to the user. Would you consider a [listbox](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/listbox-dropdown/) UX instead?

Answer (score 0):

### `datalist` element is hidden in rendering

According to [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-datalist-element):

> In the rendering, the datalist element represents nothing and it, along with its children, should be hidden.

What you describe in the question and screenshot seems to be the expected behavior: i.e. displaying the list of `option`s when `input` is active. If you need to display the list at all times, perhaps you might want to consider an additional (or an alternative) element to do that.